# Why are some of the background images shaking while transitioning the background-size property?

Tags: html, css

I wanted to create the same effect as this tutorial (1 minute long):
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_1vEGYWaaQY&ab_channel=KevinPowell

So there's a background image that creates the underline effect like the tutorial above showed, I made the background bigger than an underline just to be more clear, now some of these background images are working properly but some of them start shaking when the transition starts

I tried changing the first letter of the text and the shaking was gone, it's so weird, it should be a bug with the browser or something(I'm using Chrome on Windows 10) because the CSS is fine I guess, is there any fix for this issue?

You can see two different texts, but with the same CSS styles:

This is the broken one, just notice the first line of the text (top right beside the letter "و") when I hover the mouse on the text and when the background-size transitions to 100%, the beginning piece of the background starts to shake

[image]

And this is another text, but with the same CSS styles as the text above, notice the beginning piece of this background image holds still and it's not shaking (beside the letter "مـ")

[image]

Maybe this problem is just because I'm using another language... I don't know

HTML:

```
<li id="EachNews">
    <div>
        <h2><a>(The texts in the GIFs which loads from database...)</a></h2>
    </div>
</li>
```

CSS:

```
:root {
    --main: #6c4fff;
    --title: #B3B3B3;
}
#EachNews h2 {
    margin-top: -11px;
    width: 400px;
    transition: all 2s ease-out;
}

#EachNews h2 a {
    line-height: 27px;
    color: var(--title);
    font-family: 'vazir FD';
    font-weight: 500;
    background-image: linear-gradient(120deg, #CA4FFF, var(--main));
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: bottom right;
    background-size: 0% 15px;
    transition: background-size 300ms ease-in-out;
}

#EachNews h2:hover a {
    background-size: 100% 15px;
}
```

```css
:root {
  --main: #6c4fff;
  --title: #B3B3B3;
}

body {
  direction: rtl;
}

.EachNews h2 {
  margin-top: 50px;
  width: 400px;
  transition: all 2s ease-out;
  direction: rtl;
}

.EachNews h2 a {
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 30px;
  direction: rtl;
  color: var(--title);
  font-family: 'vazir FD';
  font-weight: 500;
  background-image: linear-gradient(120deg, #CA4FFF, var(--main));
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: right bottom;
  background-size: 0% 15px;
  transition: background-size 300ms ease-in-out;
}

.EachNews h2:hover a {
  background-size: 100% 15px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="EachNews">
    <div>
      <h2><a>محققان با عکس سیستم احراز هویت ویندوز Hello مایکروسافت را فریب دادند</a></h2>
    </div>
  </li>

  <li class="EachNews">
    <div>
      <h2><a>وزارت دادگستری آمریکا: دادستان‌ها هدف حمله سایبری هکرهای سولار ویندز بوده‌اند</a></h2>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

EDIT: Even with a shorter text the shaking still happens, in my project the shaking is more obvious than the code snippet, I don't know if you should count on the code snippet or not, but I think this is related to browser bugs or something... because the problem changes by multiple factors, like changing the first letter or zooming in, in the browser etc...

[image]

And after I zoom in 175% in my browser, the shaking is gone:

[image]

Comment: what is the value of `--main`?

Comment: @amirify it's just a color variable (#6c4fff), I added it to the CSS codes

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem using the code you have given, which is LTR English. Perhaps you could put up a snippet which we could run with your font so we can see the problem for ourselves, though I guess we'd have assumed that RTL shouldn't make a difference to the CSS background image but it's worth a try.

Comment: Looks like a bug you sometime have with italic fonts on the edges(drawn partially outside the container). give it a small padding or text-indent to move a bit that letter from the edge and see if that shaking visual effects remains.

Comment: @AHaworth I added a code snippet

Comment: @G-Cyrillus I tried adding a bit of padding to the h2 but that didn't help either

Comment: It is the a tag involved here :) even inline it can take horizontal padding or text-indent

Comment: @G-Cyrillus adding padding to the a tag didn't fix it either, I think this problem is more of a browser side problem, because zooming in on the browser would also corrupt some of those proper working background images to also start shaking, or fix those that were not working, I don't know, but in my project, adding padding to the a tag didn't fix the shaking at all, and in my own project the shaking is a bit more obvious than the code snippet above, that's why I didn't add a code snippet at first, because I think this problem changes it's behavior by multiple factors, idk it's just so weird

Comment: Okay, did you try a reflow, like setting position :relative  to the a tag?

Comment: @G-Cyrillus didn't work, I was expecting one of those webkit fixes :s, because having other elements that have the exact same style working properly and then also having another element with the same style NOT working can't be a CSS problem imo

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem on my system, but I'm suspicious of the 120deg - there can be edge effects when the browser has to calculate how many actual screen pixels to show for a part CSS pixel (on modern screens there isn't a 1-1 mapping). Does removing 120deg have any effect?

Comment: @AHaworth no, removing 120deg didn't have any effect

Comment: last ideas (i can't reproduce either your issue), set an offset position to you background alike : background-position: 110% 100%; . What about the zoom value set on your browser for that page ? Is also your HTML code valid ?

Comment: @G-Cyrillus I think setting the background-position: 110% 100% actually fixed it! :D It's not shaking anymore, I hope it stays like this :s THANK YOU SO MUCH, add your answer and I'll accept it so it's obvious for others as well... Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From comments.

> last ideas (i can't reproduce either your issue), set an offset position to you background alike : `background-position: 110% 100%;`

It will make the background coming from outside the container and should avoid an average calculation for right/100%.

Answer (score 0):

its because the padding ,, in some UTF-8 fonts you will need to add 2px or so
for example:

```css
.EachNews a{
    padding: 3px;
}
```

#### edit:

```css
:root {
  --main: #6c4fff;
  --title: #B3B3B3;
}

body {
  direction: rtl;
}

.EachNews h2 {
  margin-top: 50px;
  width: 400px;
  transition: all 2s ease-out;
  direction: rtl;
}

.EachNews h2 a {
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 30px;
  direction: rtl;
  color: var(--title);
  font-family: 'vazir FD';
  font-weight: 500;
  background-image: linear-gradient(120deg, #CA4FFF, var(--main));
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: right bottom;
  background-size: 0% 15px;
  transition: background-size 300ms ease-in-out;
      padding: 3px;
}

.EachNews h2:hover a {
  background-size: 100% 15px;
 
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="EachNews">
    <div>
      <h2><a>محققان با عکس سیستم احراز هویت ویندوز Hello مایکروسافت را فریب دادند</a></h2>
    </div>
  </li>

  <li class="EachNews">
    <div>
      <h2><a>وزارت دادگستری آمریکا: دادستان‌ها هدف حمله سایبری هکرهای سولار ویندز بوده‌اند</a></h2>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for your input, but adding a padding property didn't solve the issue

Answer (score 0):

After playing around with code I noticed two things. First, this happens only when text-align is set to right, and second, the problem is not with the letters, the shaking happens when text is long. So I think one option to solve your problem is to truncate your text. I have added two links with different lenghth so you can check it out.

```css
html {
  direction: rtl;
}

body {
  padding: 15px;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 15px;
}

#EachNews h2 {
    margin-top: -11px;
    width: 400px;
    transition: all 2s ease-out;
    margin-top: 50px;
}

#EachNews h2 a {
    line-height: 27px;
    color: #000000;
    font-family: 'vazir FD';
    font-weight: 500;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-image: linear-gradient(120deg, #CA4FFF, #ff0000);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: top right;
    background-size: 0 20px;
    transition: background-size 300ms ease-in-out;
}

#EachNews h2:hover a {
    background-size: 100% 20px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li id="EachNews">
    <div>
      <h2>
        <a href="#">
        وزارت دادگستری شسیب شسیب شسیب شسیب شسیب شسیب شسیب سشیب شسیب سشیب سشیب شسیب شسیب سشیب شسیب شس بسشی بسب ستشی تسیب سنیت بنشس سشیب شسیب سشیب سیب شسیب شسیب شسی بب
        وزارت دادگستری شسیب شسیب شسیب شسیب شسیب شسیب شسیب سشیب شسیب سشیب سشیب شسیب شسیب سشیب شسیب شس بسشی بسب ستشی تسیب سنیت بنشس سشیب شسیب سشیب سیب شسیب شسیب شسی بب
        </a>
      </h2>
      <h2>
        <a href="#">
        وزارت دادگستری شسیب شسیب شسیب شسیب شسیب شسیب شسیب سشیب شسیب سشیب سشیب شسیب شسیب
        </a>
      </h2>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: In my project, even if I shorten the length of the text, it's still shaking, I'll add a gif to my question that how it's behaving